# Why does Chrome have two encoding settings?

Tags: google-chrome, encoding

I can change the encoding for Chrome under settings→advanced→web content→customize fonts.

I can also change it via Menu→More tools→Encoding.

One setting does not change the other. So why are there two ways to set the encoding? If they are equivalent, which takes prevalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Settings* sets the default encoding applied to all pages which do not declare one.

*Menu→Tools* changes (overrides) the encoding used for the current page.

Comment: Cool, in that case I found that defaulting to unicode causes some extensions to misbehave (like showing chinese characters in an english dictionary extension). But if the Tools choice overrides the declared encoding, isn't it better to always use auto-detect?

Comment: "Unicode" as in UTF-8 or as in UTF-16? The latter is evil.

Comment: I always try for UTF-8

Comment: Then it probably just means a buggy extension... Quite a few sites used to be lazy and just assume ISO-8859-1, it's why browsers still use it as the default.

Comment: Aw just noticed the SE app doesn't render the above arrows properly  But hard to tell if the problem is the encoding or the font.

Comment: All means of overriding content encoding in Chrome seem to have dissappeared as of late 2016 or at least today in January 2017, at least on pages that arrive with a BOM (byte-order marker) at the beginning, which can be interpreted to guarantee that the content is in Unicode.